# Scroll a timeline

Tags: plotting

I started using TimelinePlot, and I'm embarking in the production of a rather large timeline, so I'm worrying about the visualization.
Is it possible to insert a scrollbar (horizontal or vertical) in the final timeline?

Comment: Have you looked at `Manipulate[]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you mean this?

```
data = {{Interval[{DateObject[{1997, 7, 29}], 
  DateObject[{2000, 3, 18}]}], 
Interval[{DateObject[{1999, 1, 8}], DateObject[{2004, 4, 4}]}], 
Interval[{DateObject[{2001, 10, 26}], 
  DateObject[{2012, 1, 7}]}]}, {Interval[{DateObject[{1993, 2, 
    2}], DateObject[{1996, 8, 18}]}], 
Interval[{DateObject[{2003, 7, 2}], DateObject[{2006, 4, 3}]}], 
Interval[{DateObject[{2004, 10, 19}], 
  DateObject[{2006, 3, 2}]}]}};
Pane[TimelinePlot[data, PlotLayout -> "Grouped"], 
 ImageSize -> {400, 100}, Scrollbars -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm curious, can this be done with regular `Plot[]` too? Because I looked into that and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Feyre It's seem there are some behavior is unexpected.But this code work well still.`Pane[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, ImageSize -> Large], 
 ImageSize -> {400, 100}, Scrollbars -> True]`

Comment: Curious, that's working fine, must have had an minor aneurysm.

Comment: @Feyre I'm very peaceful now when I encounter aneurysm in *Mathematica* :)

Comment: that's good - exactly what I needed thank you!